# php file/folder treeview with descriptions script?

Tags: php, file, browser

I am displaying a file/folder structure using a treeview component using PHP, for an online library. Now I need to be able to add optional descriptions to each folder/file, so I guess I need to cross this with a mysql database. I was wondering if someone knows of an opensource script that will let you do this, so as not to have to write it from scratch?

Basically it should map a server folder/file structure to a mysql database, let you upload files and new folders, along with descriptions and allow navigation of the structure via a webpage.

Thanks!

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Try the PEAR::HTML_Tree